# Google Charts - Change the color of column in clickable label ColumnChart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynguyen203/5SX8w/108/) example

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
        // setting the "isStacked" option to true fixes the spacing problem
        isStacked: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        series: [{color: 'blue', visibleInLegend: false}, 
                {color: 'red', visibleInLegend:false}]

    }
});
```

How can I change the color  column when clickable label on a google chart API bar chart?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRIb9.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the chart's `'click'` event to determine if an axis label has been clicked.
the event will return a property for --> `targetId`

if an x-axis labels was clicked, the `targetID` will have the following format.

```
hAxis#[series]label#[row]
```

e.g.

```
hAxis#0label#0
```

then you can change the color based on the label clicked.
but you will also need to consider the last label clicked,
as well as any selection made with the `'select'` event.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addRows([
    ['Foo', 94],
    ['Bar', 23],
    ['Baz', 80],
    ['Bat', 47],
    ['Cad', 32],
    ['Qud', 54]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      height: 300,
      width: 600,
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function (props) {
    var currentSelection = null;

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart.getChart(), 'click', function (props) {
      var target = props.targetID;
      if ((target.indexOf('hAxis#') > -1) && (target.indexOf('label#') > -1)) {
        target = target.split('#');
        setSelection(parseInt(target[target.length - 1]));
      }
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      setSelection(getSelection());
    });

    function getSelection() {
      var rowIndex = null;
      var selection = chart.getChart().getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        rowIndex = selection[0].row;
      }
      return rowIndex;
    }

    function setSelection(rowSelected) {
      if (rowSelected === currentSelection) {
        currentSelection = null;
      } else {
        currentSelection = rowSelected;
      }
      google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function (props) {
        if (currentSelection === null) {
          chart.getChart().setSelection([]);
        } else {
          chart.getChart().setSelection([{row: currentSelection, column: 1}]);
        }
      });
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          return (row === currentSelection) ? '00A0D0' : null;
        },
        role: 'style',
        type: 'string'
      }]);
      chart.setDataTable(view);
      chart.draw();
    }
  });

  chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**NOTES** (see above snippet)

first, you can use a `'style'` column role to change the color of an individual row.
this will prevent having to add options to account for an additional series of data.

next, you can use `addOneTimeEventListener` so you don't have to remove the event later.

finally, recommend using the newer library `loader.js`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

instead of `jsapi`, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement...